# Different ordering of bones in Blender than in Python

Tags: python, blender

My modelexporter mostly works, but I added an extra bone to a model, named the bone 'gun' and in my script this bone's index is 5 (connected to 'stump'). The vertices attached to this bone, has the index 10. I clicked around in the windows, and the Graph editor shows the gun-bone is the last, the 10th. Here's a pic side by side:
wrong order:
[image: wrong order]

How can I get the proper order in Python?

Comment: You're comparing action with armature, and they have pretty much nothing in common. You can read from action (e.g. `bpy.data.actions[0].groups`) if you have to, but even in that case I wouldn't assume it absolutely have to match what interface shows, as it can apply different sorting rules. Why is that important to you?

Comment: My workflow is like this: I make the model, then the armature, parent them with automatic weights, then make some animation in the dope-sheet window, like walking, shooting etc. Then I export it with a python script to a text format, so my engine can use it. To make animation work, I need bone matrices and vertex with weights and bone-indices to know which bones infulences the said vertex. But I cannot get the proper bone ordering when I add a new bone after making the parenting and animation, during the customization of the model.

Comment: I don't really get your problem, can you edit your pseudocode into the question? So far I don't see why order is important at all, as both bone and its vertex group share the same name. Can't you use any order, as long as it is the same in both mesh and armature? Relying only on action is probably not the best since some bones may have no animation assigned and hence they will not appear in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All collections in blender are of type [`bpy_prop_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html). This collection functions both like a dictionary and a list, allowing items to be referenced either by index or name. Like a dictionary you can't rely on the items being in a specific order, either by name or creation order.

As there is no guarantee that a new item added to the collection will get the highest index number, each export will need to be aligned with the index at the time of export and not trying to re-use indexes of previous exports.

You should find that enumerating the bones list will give the same index numbers that are used internally, you can get blenders internal index number of a bone by using the collections `find()`

```
for i, b in enumerate(rig.bones):
    print(i, rig.bones.find(b.name), b.name)


0 0 spine
1 1 spine.001
2 2 spine.003
3 3 spine.004
4 4 spine.005
5 5 spine.006
6 6 shoulder.L
7 7 upper_arm.L
...
```

Bones move vertices that are assigned a weight in a [vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) with a name matching the bone. So the bone named "shoulder.L" will move vertices that have been assigned a weight to vertex group named "shoulder.L". Expanding on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27509/935) you can access each vertices group weight.

```
grpid = obj.data.vertices[0].groups[0].group
bone_name = obj.vertex_groups[grpid].name
vert_bone_weight = obj.data.vertices[0].groups[0].weight
```

Comment: Yes, I realized this after checking the exported file. Index dosen't matter, only names count. Luckily I export each pose's name and saw there is a mixup in the animation matrices order. (armature.pose.bones)
Sorting pose matrices by the bones' names fixes the problem. Thank you for clarifying.